# How to call Ajax to remove a record from my database without reloading the page

Tags: php, ajax

I want to remove a some record from my database while clicking on delete button. Currently I am using this code:

```
function removeItem(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url:"removeItem_checkOut.php",  
        type:"GET",
        data:"id="+id,
        success:function(content) {
            window.location.reload(); 
        }
    });
}
```

In removeItem_checkOUt.php I am simply running the delete query.

It works fine for me, but the problem with this code is that it reload the entire page. I just want to do it without reloading the page.

Simple saying is this that the functionality of the above code is good but i am unable to do it without the reloading the page. Until the page reload, it is does not disappear for the page.
Can anyone help me please....

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "window.location.reload();" line from your success callback.

This line is telling your ajax call to reload the window after it has been successfully executed.

Comment: Dear Fyntasia you are right it works but until  reloading the page the item displays here in the page. It looks like that it is not been deleted, in fact it is... When I refresh the page is disappears.

Comment: This would require you to modify the DOM based on the success result.
If you know where or what to modify, you can do it from your success callback.

Comment: You can check it by visiting pizzahut.com.pk/home/cart.php. Add some items in the cart and try to remove it

Comment: Like I said in my previous comment, Let your removal script return an identifier for the removed product, then search the DOM for the corresponding item and .remove() it.

Comment: Well, I'm not going to write a custom piece of code for your application.
I'd suggest you look into jquery and how to select an object in your DOM and delete it based on a unique identifier.

Comment: You're welcome friend, I hope you will succeed in your endeavour!

Answer (score 1):

```
function removeItem(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url:"removeItem_checkOut.php",  
        type:"GET",
        data:"id="+id,
        success:function(html) {
               $('#div_contains_data').html(html); //put your div id of the content (if it is a table use that table inside a div) 
        }
    });
}
```

and in your `removeItem_checkOut.php` print again the same data part that the div contains(here assumed as table.so print the table in your php file again).

Comment: Respected #Kavin Smk. It works for me except this issue, that when i click delete it works fine and also hide the table. The table is "tbody" which contain the data. removeItem_checkOut.php code is: 

mysql_query("DELETE FROM `temporary` WHERE `id`='$id' "). How to print the table again ?

Comment: When i click delete it works fine and also hide the table. The table name is "tbody" which contain the data. removeItem_checkOut.php code is here below: 

mysql_query("DELETE FROM temporary WHERE id='$id' "). How to print the table again ?

Comment: by using select query for the table data. and print it as a table again